# Can I use wallet balance in satoshis as input for transaction builder ( bitcoinjs-lib )?

Tags: bitcoinjs, satoshi

Can I use wallet balance in satoshis as input for transaction builder using [bitcoinjs-lib](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib) ?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Bitcoins are not kept in addresses, but Unspent Outputs ("UTXO"). You must specify TXIDs and outputs indices ("vout"). Specifying amount to make a transaction is not needed, but BitcoinJS may ask you for it to calculate the change output and the fee.